# Fix to prevent Firefox from Highlighting Select Option set

Tags: html, css, firefox, windows-7

Here's some very simple sample HTML for purposes of this question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>stuff</p>
<p>more stuff</p>
<label>Test</label>
<select>
    <option>Option 1 Here</option>
    <option>Option 2 Here</option>
    <option>Option 3 Here</option>
    <option>Option 4 Here</option>
    <option>Option 5 Here</option>
    <option>Option 6 Here</option>
    <option>Option 7 Here</option>
</select>   
<p>other stuff</p>
</body>
</html>
```

On Firefox 12.0 on Windows 7, when you highlight the text with the cursor surrounding the `<select>`, the options are also highlighted.

[image]

This behavior does not happen in other modern browsers I've tested, such as IE9 and Chrome.

Basically, I want to allow highlighting of surrounding text, but I never want to allow highlighting of options in the select as firefox is doing.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) involving disabling highlighting.  I tried it at first as:

```
    body {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;  
}
```

This succeeded in disabling highlighting on the `<select>` however, nothing else could be highlighted which is not preferred.

I attempted to narrow the scope of the CSS rule to:

```
    select, select option {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;  
}
```

However, this did not work as can be seen in the following screen shot.  Although firebug states the rule was applied to the `<select>` element the highlighting is still permitted.

Normally it wouldn't be a big deal, but this is a small tidbit from a larger application that relies on many scrolling `<div>` elements that inadvertently lend to highlighting selects whilst scrolling.  Though, I don't want a solution that involves users not being able to select any text at all as that is not the experience they are used to.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
option::-moz-selection { background: transparent; }
```

Comment: I've tested it out, and this rule alone fixed the issue.  Good answer.